# Touble with saving excel sheet/ making changes -- Python openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to automate the process of creating new cost sheets at my work.
I have a functional code that pulls the source file, renames it, moves it where I want it, etc.

I am trying to use openpyxl to write in some of the data that is parsed in creating the file/directory name. I can't posst my full ncode because it has work directories and such in it but here's the failing portion:

```
############################
#Write Info Into Cost Sheet#
############################

myworkbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(new_CSdst_file_name)
worksheet= myworkbook['COST SHEET']
worksheet['C3']= now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
worksheet['C5']='SOW-'+line_split[2]
worksheet['C6']='CS-'+line_split[4]
worksheet['C10']='0'
worksheet['J4']=line_split[3]
#myworkbook.save(new_CSdst_file_name)
```

If the save is commented out the file is created, but no cells are filled.
If I uncomment the save I get the attached excel error (see image)

Going home for the day, but any help appreciated. Will check in Monday!

[Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8lh6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please provide some sample data, so we can see what the workbook looks like?

Comment: does it work, if you save the file as .xlsx (instead of .xlsm)?

Comment: @Greg thanks for pointing out file type. Can't save as xlsx  as that would disable macros AFAIK, But you put me down the right path on Google to find the answer in another Stack Exchange question.  I needed vba true: 'wb = load_workbook('Test.xlsm',keep_vba=True)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Greg 's comment I was able to find another answer that provided the solution.
Working code here:

```
    myworkbook=openpyxl.load_workbook(new_CSdst_file_name, keep_vba=True)
    worksheet= myworkbook['COST SHEET'] #Open Sheet Named COST SHEET (current Sheet 1 name in xlsm)
    worksheet['C3']= now.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") #Date
    worksheet['C5']='SOW-'+ PartNum #SOW number
    worksheet['C6']='CS-'+ PartNum #CS number
    worksheet['C7']= Description #descriptor
    worksheet['C10']='0' #creating revision 0
    worksheet['J4']= Customer #Company Name
    myworkbook.save(new_CSdst_file_name)
```